# Way to share HD multi-cam long media files to preview edits

Tags: premiere

I'm working with a team, we make some review videos for automobile/cars. There are in-car shots with 3 way multi-cam scenario, sometimes 1 out-car shot may come.

We have 3 producers. There is no strong work of compositing right now, just video editing. However editing is very complicated, sometimes there may be 10 cuts over 10 secs. It should also be managed by all producers, however the media is usually over 40 GBs. It is impossible to transfer this data via internet atm, I lastly found out proxy is intuitive for that kind of work.

We need to figure out the best (at least, optimal) way with performance and time aspects, what do you prefer? Only one may render the final work, we have no issue with that. But there should be a way to preview our work (as a project file) to the director.

Some tech stuff:
Videos are basically **2 hours** before editing and **the final video comes like 30 mins**, not more than 45 mins. There are two **1080p** cameras and one **720p** camera recording at 24.97, 60 fps and 29.97 fps, respectively. Audio is recorded at 16-bit 44100 Hz PCM mono. The audio channels of videos are deleted right after sync.

Comment: It sounds like your major hurdle is transferring the data, correct?  As long as all of your people are using the same software and have copies of the camera originals, you should just be able to email small .xml .edl or project files to communicate edits with your partners.  To get a copy of the originals in everyone's hands, consider physically mailing hard drives.  That, or web hosts like DropBox.

Comment: Sound like you nailed it there, I work on projects from my Mac Pro and MacBookPro.

I have all mead copied on both devices and backed up on a Extenral HDD

Comment: Why are you jumbling your frame rates?  That's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the other problems you have in your current pipeline, I would just transcode your source files to a low quality, low res intermediate proxy.  Have other editors work off the low quality, small size videos and simply replace the proxy in the final render.

There will be some minor losses in this process due to things like color changes and such from the compression on the proxies, but a final color grading pass will counteract that largely and either way, the problems you are going to get from the various frame rates and resolutions far overshadow the very minor issues you'll get from using the low quality proxies.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you nailed it there, I work on projects from my Mac Pro and MacBookPro.

I have all mead copied on both devices and backed up on a Extenral HDD
Using FCPX I start the edit on one machine and then DropBox or GoogleDrive the project file (As all the media is kept separate from the project)
I then can just drop it back into  the folder and it will be up to date.

I only work like this as I do most of my editing at home but use my MBP while on lunches at work etc

I would jsut pop all the media on a Ext USB HDD and mail the original files and project folder structure as long as this all stays the same it should be effort less, otherwise using some proxy files using a standard file and folder structure so it is all kept to this standard.

all my project use the same structure which means I always know where my files are and if anything happens I know where to look straight away